# How Does A PC Know To Use Another Domain Controller When Its Regular Domain Controller Is Offline

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I condider myself to have a very good understanding of Active Directory and I am aware of the obvious benefits of having more than one domain controller in a domain.

My question is basically this. When one domain controller is not available, how does a PC in the domain know to revert to another domain controller?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does `nslookup your.domain` return? :)

Comment: @jscott, thanks for the quick reply. It simply returns the IP address of the current domain controller/dns server (My current network only has a single domain controller). My question is simply curiosity based and not practical based.

Comment: Here you go, the DC Locator process: http://blogs.technet.com/b/arnaud_jumelet/archive/2010/07/05/domain-controller-locator-an-overview.aspx

Comment: @joeqwerty Link answers suck but that is by far the best answer to this question.  I'd post it anyway.

Comment: I was being lazy so I posted the link as a comment instead of a full answer with the link included. It looks like @Greg Askew got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's known as the DC Locator process.

https://blogs.technet.com/b/arnaud_jumelet/archive/2010/07/11/domain-controller-locator-in-depth.aspx

**How DNS Support for Active Directory Works**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759550%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

DNS returns a list of DC's sorted by priority and weight.  The client attempts to communicate with a DC, and moves to the next DC in the list if a response is not received in a brief period.

**5.4.5.3 Ping the Candidate Domain Controllers for "Liveness" and Capability Verification Using LDAP Ping Mechanism**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718294%28v=prot.20%29.aspx

If the client cannot locate a DC in it's site, or if the client is not in a site, it will attempt to contact any domain controller in the domain.